# Should the link be removed from this post

Tags: discussion, specific-question, hyperlinks

I stumbled across this post: [VBA - Match Lookup With Multiple Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50227693/vba-vlookup-with-multiple-parameters)

The question itself is of not too high quality, and might even be too broad. However the OP self-answered the question with the solution gained elsewhere.

The answer is not link-only, as it includes relevant code to solve the problem, but could use some explanation besides just the code. One might think to get that extra explanation behind the link, however the answer isn't readily accessible there, it requires one to register at least (I haven't done so).
Should this link be removed from the answer as it:

1. Promotes another Q&A-site / forum
2. Adds no value

Or is there no harm in keeping the link in the answer?

Comment: If anything the author of that code should be attributed. Assuming EE has a license that allows copying I see no problem. If you remove the link the OP will be accused of plagiarism so that is not the way forward.

Comment: I can view the solution in the link without having to register. I just clicked view solution below the "join now" button...

Comment: @rene from their TOS: "8. Content License

    When you post content to the Site ("Your Content"), you understand and agree that Your Content can be viewed and used by other Members who visit the Site with or without attribution. " So attribution isn't required I think.

Comment: @André there is timeout for that link to be available though. Missed it myself first time around.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, that link should not be removed.

The OP is correct to include where they found that code. They should go one step further and also mention the author of that code.
I assume they act inline with what is allowed by the ToS of that site. Even if the other site allows copying without attribution, we still can keep our self to an higher standard.

Without attribution the code could be seen as plagiarized and when Brad finds out you'll not be happy.

That the link *promotes* another site is a non-issue. Other sites *promote* us as well. This balances out nicely.

Comment: I edited in attribution.